# Converting a Term Document Matrix to a Term Document Matrix supported by tm library

Tags: r

I have a csv file, where I have all of my documents stemmed in a Term Document Matrix form and a categorical variable as a sentiment.
I'd like to use `tm`'s capabilities (terms frequencies etc.). Is there a way to do so, given the data I started with?

```
# given:

dtm = read.csv(file_path, na.strings="") 
dtm$rating = as.factor(dtm$rating)

str(dtm)
# 'data.frame': 2000 obs. of  2002 variables:
# $ ID           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ abl          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# ...

head(dtm)
#ID abl absolut absorb accept 
#1  1   0       0      0      
#2  2   0       0      1

# I'd like to achieve...
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(dtm,
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE))
```

Comment: is dtm already a data.frame of term frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `as.TermDocumentMatrix(df, weighting = weightTf)` (in the R package `tm`) to do what you seek?